# Active Directory: Password history check before lock out user

Tags: windows, active-directory

How to configure Active Directory to do a password history check before increment the bad password count and lock out a user?

This [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/4b9f3fdd-f6e0-4a55-af99-ec065fe1b785/password-history-check-n2?forum=winserverGP) exactly describes what I want. Unfortunately it references a [deprecated documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780271(v=ws.10).aspx)):

> Password history check (N-2): Before a Windows Server 2003 operating system increments badPwdCount, it checks the invalid password against the password history. If the password is the same as one of the last two entries that are in the password history, badPwdCount is not incremented for both NTLM and the Kerberos protocol. This change to domain controllers should reduce the number of lockouts that occur because of user error.

So how can I do that with new Windows Server releases?

Comment: I'm not the administrator but the bothered user of my company's AD. So I could not exactly say how the AD is configured currently. My goal is to give the admin a hint to do it better.

Comment: That thread and documentation may still be relevant. The consensus in the thread seemed to be that this feature is automatically enabled only if password history is enforced (i.e. it does not let you use an old password when you change your password). Does your organization let you use old passwords when you change your password?

Comment: That was also my understanding. But no, I'm not allowed to use old passwords. Nevertheless I'm locked out when my mobile makes requests with my old password. So I will ask them what they did really configure in the AD.